# Tor stuck at establishing a connection

Tags: linux, tor-install

I'm trying to use the Tor web browser to bypass my school's Barracuda and FortiNET web filter. I used a bootable linux USB to get Tor but when I try and connect it just sits at Establishing a Connection, and under the green bar it just sits at 'Retrieving network status'

Comment: Have you tried a bridge? https://tb-manual.torproject.org/bridges/

Comment: You have to use a bridge. Because your school blocks the connection to tor already.